# How can I use a parameter of a function to use data of an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a game in which I would like to load a level. I am trying to set this up in a way to simplify it.

I already tried using:

```
function loadLevel(name) { return fetch(`./levels/${name}.json`).then(r => r.json());.
```

This did not work as it would not even load the level I have saved in another file. I tested this using console.log. This was my json, saved in a file named 1-1:

```
{
  "backgrounds": [
    {
      "tile": "sky",
      "ranges": [
        [
          0, 25,
          0, 14
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought that having an object that sets my level would do the trick:

```
var levels = {
    "1-1": {
        backgrounds: [
            {
                tile: "sky",
                ranges: [[0, 25, 0, 16]]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Above is how I need to have each variable, and then I need to pass it eventually through something like this:

```
function drawBackground(backgrounds, ctx, sprites) {
    backgrounds.ranges.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => {
        for (let x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
            for(let y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
                sprites.drawTile(background.tile, ctx, x, y);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However, the issue comes when I want to load a level. I have a function that runs this:

```
loadImage('./img/tiles.PNG').then(image => { //loadImage is a function that runs an image
    const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16); //Takes in image and tile size

    sprites.define('ground', 0, 0); //sets a key for the tile and a position on the spritesheet image
    sprites.define('sky', 3, 23);
    loadLevel('1-1')// *This is the function I would like to pass the object thru
    .then(level => {
    drawBackground(level.backgrounds[0], ctx, sprites); //Does the above
});
```

Now that I have listed all of my code that is relevant, now this is my issue:

I want to edit the loadLevel function so I can pick a level to load using an object, but not sure exactly how I can do so. I meant to do it similar to the fetch() method. Another possible solution would be to run it through the drawBackground() function.

```
//maybe like this:
function drawBackground(name, ctx, sprites) {
//Below, I know ${name} will not work but an idea of a possible solution
  levels.${name}.backgrounds.ranges.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => { 
    for (let x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
      for(let y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
        sprites.drawTile(background.tile, ctx, x, y);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

All I need to do is load the level and it's attributes in order to draw it. If you have any questions, I can provide more assistance in my question if needed, whether it be in full/more code or other answers/explanations.

EDIT: A possible way of fixing this via the method of accessing the object can be found at another question here: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square bracket notation:

```
function drawBackground(name, ctx, sprites) {
    levels[name].backgrounds.ranges.forEach(...);
}
```